# jquery issue with FireFox specific

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have following code for user to allow only **alphabetic characters**, “**-**“, “ **’** ”

```
$('.regx').on("keypress", function (event) {
        var englishAlphabet = /[a-zA-Z-']/g;
        var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
        if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 45 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 8  || event.keyCode == 37 || englishAlphabet.test(key)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

But the issue is with " **%** " key.If I removed keycode==37 then it works fine in Chrome but in FireFox left arrow is not working fine.
Can anyone please correct the code?

Comment: If all you want is /[a-zA-Z-']/g, then why don't you just only do: if (englishAlphabet.test(key)) {
            return true;
        }   No need for examining the keyCode value, which seems to be redundant with the regex check.

Comment: If I do this then backspace,left/right keys are not working in FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

Adding the backspace into the regex expression:

```
$('.regx').on("keypress", function (event) {
    var englishAlphabet = /[a-zA-Z-'\b]/;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var browser = navigator.userAgent;
    if( browser.match(/chrome/i) ){    
        if (englishAlphabet.test(key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }else{
        if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 9 || englishAlphabet.test(key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lw6Ke/27/)

Comment: now tab is not working in FF.And if say to add key code 9 for that then there will be no any difference between your code and my code...:(. And also with your code in Chrome it is allowing to enter " % ".

Comment: Added "event.keyCode == 9" in the condition and the tab works now. What's the issue trying to solve now?

Comment: Issue is it is allowing user to enter % in Chrome.And it is because of same key code for % and left arrow key.

Comment: yes, that's what I see as well. the keycode for % in Chrome is 37, which happens to be the keycode of <- on FF.

Comment: Looks like you are going to need to split the cases using var browser = navigator.userAgent;  See the updated version above

Comment: And keep in mind that Firefox's setting might not the most desirable "default" setup, given that there are IE, safari, and other browsers out there.

Comment: Yes Kyo you are right.The updated code is working fine in both browser.Since I am using this code in my current development site, I need to verify it in both chrome as well as in FF also.

Comment: Kyo!Can you please tell me for IE browser what I need to do in this code?The % key issue exists in IE.

Comment: You will need to figure out what the key % is mapped to on IE and create a special case for IE browser

Comment: I have searched the keycode for % key IE specific but did not get any result.If you have solution then please provide it with the above code.

Comment: I do not have IE handy on my machines. You will need to get access to IE browser and test it for yourself to find out what keycode % is mapped to.

Comment: Keycode is same as 37 for IE also but Explorer doesn't fire the keypress event.

Comment: It seems like this IE issue could a question of its own then :) As mentioned above, I do not have IE accessible at the moment, so there is no way for me to debug which event gets triggered on IE's inputbox when a key is pressed. Sorry.

Comment: Find out what IE's event is, then consolidate the event handler $('.regx').on("keypress", function (event) { } to includes all 3 browsers. For instance, try "keyup" instead of "keypress"; it's a more common key stroke detector than "keypress". Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Kayo and browser.match(/(chrome)|(ie)/i) ) works for me.But a new challenge I am facing-although special character is not allowed to enter validation is working fine but when user copy special characters from notepad and paste that in the fields then it is allowing user to to that.How can I prevent this?

Comment: Not sure on the exact purpose of the validation, but you will need to perform the live validation on the "keyup" event on the value of the input itself to ensure that all characters are valid. What you doing is trying to prevent "per character" validation as being typed, which is not the best way to go about this issue.